# List Objects Disposed Automatically C#

Tags: c#

I have Public List contains custom objects, that I have declared into a windows Form

```
private List<ConnectedClient> connectedClients = new List<ConnectedClient>();
```

and I add object to it in certain event when client bind

```
private void server_evClientBind(object sender, ServerClient client, Bind data)
{
lock (connectedClients)
   {
       connectedClients.Add(clientDTO);
   }
 }
```

and when client submit message, I filter connectedClients List on event server_evClientSubmitSm by the client object received data then decide to accept it or reject from the client

```
private void server_evClientSubmitSm(object sender, ServerClient client, SubmitSm data)
    {
        try
        {                
            ConnectedClient clientDto = null;
            lock (connectedClients)
            {
                clientDto = connectedClients.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.ServerClient.SystemID) && c.ServerClient.SystemID.Trim() == client.SystemID.Trim()
                && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Address != null && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Address == client.LocalEndPoint.Address
                && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Port > new int() && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Port == client.LocalEndPoint.Port).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (clientDto != null)
            {
                //receive Message
            }
            else
            {
                //object not exist 
            }
        }
    }
```

but after application sleep or on hold(client don't submit messages) for certain time period I don't know it, he back to submit messages but the below part return null

```
ConnectedClient clientDto = null;
        lock (connectedClients)
        {
            clientDto = connectedClients.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.ServerClient.SystemID) && c.ServerClient.SystemID.Trim() == client.SystemID.Trim()
            && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Address != null && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Address == client.LocalEndPoint.Address
            && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Port > new int() && c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint.Port == client.LocalEndPoint.Port).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

I guess the issue is after couple of minutes the memory release the List objects, can anyone advice?

Comment: What is the problem? What is occurring that you don't expect to occur? What do you expect to occur that isn't occurring?

Comment: You mean you observe that the list is emptied, rather than disposed? As long as the form is not closed the runtime will leave it intact, unless you interfere. By the way, since you are using locks you are probably using threading someway, that can seriously mess things up when not done proper, like locking. Tip: try using a concurrent colletion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/ . Where else is this collection used? Can you post that code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your machine goes to sleep, all connections are closed.

If you wait for a long time without doing anything, your connections are probably also closed, due to timeouts.

So, your list is not empty, and your problem has nothing to do with disposed objects.  Your list is still full, but it contains `ConnectedClient` objects that represent connections that are now closed, so their properties like `c.ServerClient` or `c.ServerClient.LocalEndPoint` are invalidated, so `Where()` fails to find a match.

The `.FirstOrDefault();` call will return the first item that is found, or `null` if no items are found.

And since no items are found, you get `null`.

Comment: He described it as an application sleep, not sure it is the machine he is talking about.

Comment: @PeterBons I do not know what an "application sleep" would be.  But in any case, I have also mentioned timeouts.